# Generate country names from IP Addresses in R and saving these as a new variable in a dataframe

Tags: r, geolocation, ip, country, ip2location

I need to R to convert IP addresses into Country names (I'm not interested in any other geolocation variables).

Let's say I have the following list of IP addresses (df).

This is my code:

```
df <- read.table(text="
ip_address
178.10.17.178
157.213.207.99
94.230.235.15
97.103.63.156
248.161.179.64
12.114.230.175
68.68.181.51
59.7.213.18
59.38.90.12
103.213.135.197", header = TRUE)

install.packages('pacman')
# load libraries
pacman::p_load(ip2location, reticulate, tidyverse)

# load IP2Location bin file
ip2location::open("C:/Users/smbc1y19/Downloads/IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.BIN/IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB123.BIN")
df <- df |>
  mutate(details =  map(ip_address, get_all)) |> 
  unnest_wider(details) 
df
```

This is the output:

```
# load IP2Location bin file
ip2location::open("/Users/me/Downloads/IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB11.BIN/IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB11.BIN")
df <- df |>
  mutate(details =  map(ip_address, get_all)) |> 
  unnest_wider(details) 

# df
# A tibble: 10 × 10
   ip_address      ip              country_short country_long            
   <chr>           <chr>           <chr>         <chr>                   
 1 178.10.17.178   178.10.17.178   DE            Germany                 
 2 157.213.207.99  157.213.207.99  US            United States of America
 3 94.230.235.15   94.230.235.15   UZ            Uzbekistan              
 4 97.103.63.156   97.103.63.156   US            United States of America
 5 248.161.179.64  248.161.179.64  -             -                       
 6 12.114.230.175  12.114.230.175  US            United States of America
 7 68.68.181.51    68.68.181.51    US            United States of America
 8 59.7.213.18     59.7.213.18     KR            Korea (Republic of)     
 9 59.38.90.12     59.38.90.12     CN            China                   
10 103.213.135.197 103.213.135.197 CN            China                   
   region      city       latitude  longitude  zipcode timezone
   <chr>       <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   
 1 Hessen      Eschborn   50.143517 8.570921   65760   +02:00  
 2 Ohio        Columbus   39.966381 -83.012772 43218   -04:00  
 3 Toshkent    Tashkent   41.264648 69.216270  700011  +05:00  
 4 Florida     Orlando    28.538340 -81.379242 32801   -04:00  
 5 -           -          0.000000  0.000000   -       -       
 6 New Jersey  Piscataway 40.554516 -74.460167 08854   -04:00  
 7 Tennessee   Camden     36.058815 -88.102158 38320   -05:00  
 8 Gyeonggi-do Seongnam   37.420624 127.126717 13118   +09:00  
 9 Guangdong   Foshan     23.026770 113.131477 528000  +08:00  
10 Jiangsu     Changzhou  31.783331 119.966667 213019  +08:00
plot_map(df$ip_address)
```

How can I change my code to save just country_long as a new variable in my dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple select() work? My understanding of your question is that you want your output to contain just the original data, `ip_address`, and an extra column, `country_long`.

```
df <- df |>
  mutate(details =  map(ip_address, get_all)) |> 
  unnest_wider(details) |>
  # Selects the desired columns and leaves out the rest
  select(ip_address, country_long)
```

Here is some documentation on R, specifically linked is the page to do with selecting and renaming columns of a dataframe: https://benwhalley.github.io/just-enough-r/selecting-columns.html